# Creating and styling groups in Raphaël

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I've just started looking at the raphael.js library for building SVG graphics in the browser. I touched on regular svg this week in the hopes of building a quick proof of concept for a product configurator. I took a line drawing of a jacket that I had in illustrator, saved it as SVG and then copy and pasted the SVG code into the HTML page.

http://jamesbillings.me/testjacket.html (doesn't work in IE)

please view the source and take a look how I'm doing it, it's very simple.

The clever thing that SVG and illustrator does is that is saves the SVG with grouping or what seemed to be called `<g id's>` and then styles the SVG with CSS. This makes it easy to quickly hit the g id's with a bit of jquery to make parts dissapear or change color. However, I'm stuggling to do this same thing in rapheal with a drawing done in illustrator.

I'd like to offer IE8 viewers this benifit which is why I'm looking at rapheal. does anyone knwo if this is doable without creating the image in code.

Comment: Can you please edit the title of the question so that it sounds better as to what you need to do, right now the title is vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a regular Raphaël user (I generally do only straight SVG and vanilla DOM JS), but from what I can tell Raphaël explicitly does not support groups (SVG `<g>` elements), as they do not exist in VML land.

The closest you can come is to create a [`set`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set) and push all the elements into that so that your JS can style them at once. It's not the convenience of items matched through CSS rules, and it isn't "live" (adding an item to a set does not cause it to get the attributes previously applied to that set), but you couldn't do that with VML anyhow.

If you must support IE8, I'm afraid this is your best option.

*Or, you could "nudge" your IE8 users to upgrade to IE9 and forget the Raphaël abstraction layer altogether and experience the raw power of pure SVG. ;)*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and as I figured. Raphael looks to be a great substitute for SVG thats cross browser, but as you say the 'raw power of SVG is better experienced without the Raphael abstraction layer'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Raphael has too many performance issues regarding output.
You say you are having problems coloring an illustrator file.
Just looked at your application on iPod and I cannot see the SVG of the clothing

You really need to build your confidence on Raphael because it shows well on old Ie and iPod

At my site I just built a significantly sized page and there is no graphics involved

While your there you might find it easier to get your head around Raphael

Also Raphael is an abstraction layer for SVG (which is also a great spec) 
However if you build your application and it's fast enough for the user base, who cares if it's slower than pure SVG

Also I think people are getting confused between an SVG loading in a browser v an SVG with all it's JavaScript code

Go here
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2#pagetop

Comment: Sorry if you can't see the svg drawing on the ipod, I may not have followed all the rules for embedding SVG in HTML. I know it works on the ipad. Try Firefox or Chrome, that should work for sure.

Comment: I checked out you site which is very cool but is very different to what I am trying to accomplish. The drawings and shapes I'm dealing with are more technical and only possible to come from an illustrator file, you cannot hand code them. So my question is how can I take a drawing created in illustrator, converted to SVG, and then convereted to rapheal, and then manipulate parts of the SVG by making it change color and parts dissapear. Because you cannot group things in raphael like SVG this is where I'm struggling. If you have any better insigth I'd love to hear. Thanks

Comment: This all has to be done live in the page by the user. Cheers.

Comment: James is it possible that you can send me the illustrator files? I have a converter on the site. I would like to see if it can handle your SVG. Here is a link to a jacket which was an SVG. This is just one format and if you just want the pure SVG that is available to..http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/p_jackets.php

Comment: Hey, sure thing. I just ftp'd it to one of my sites by all means take a look. http://jamesbillings.me/micro.ai I have been successful in converting it, I'm not sure how to have any interactive control of it though within the web page.

Comment: Ok James we are at stage 1 of the conversion. Inkscape really does a good job converting "ai" files to "svg". Here is the HTML/javascript version http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/p_micro.php. Pure javascript is also available. p_micro.php is not the only output if you want to take this forward.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. Not quite finished yet though I'm afraid. As mentioned I've already managed to convert the image to SVG like you have. I want to now interact with the image on the page like I would with raw svg. For example, as proof of concept it would be great to have a drop down select menu with option for different colors. when a certain color is chosen I can use jQuery to change colors in the Rapheal SVG drawing. I've been able to accomplish this with simple shapes, but complex ones such as this are more complicated to decipher into different sections

Comment: The SVG is huge. Can you simplify the zips? I'm out for a couple of hours, I will review this again when I get back...

Comment: haha... I know, that's my problem. And this is why I don't think Raphael is good for this situation because the SVG is indeed HUGE! However, not a problem in raw SVG but I want compatibility in IE. Can't touch the zips i'm afraid but I know what your mean, they probably make up about 90% of the code. Cheers, anyhow.